# Filtering a list

Tags: c#, .net, generics, filtering

In some cases I've been using a DataTable, filtering it witha DataView and displaying the DataView in a DataGrid.  I've recently started switching to using my own classes. For example:

```
[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Items", Namespace = "http://mycomp.com/test")]
public class Items: List<Item>
{

}

[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Item", Namespace = "http://mycomp.com/test")]
public class Item
{
  //public properties here
}
```

I then take my Items class and display it in a DataGrid which has worked really well.  Is there some way I can apply a filter to my list though?  DataView only works on datatables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FindAll() method:

```
List<Items> allItems = /* initialize list */;

List<Items> filteredList =
    allItems.FindAll(item => item.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use LINQ to Objects and bind the resulting list to the grid view...